# How do I properly reassign variables in Lua?

Tags: variables, lua, variable-assignment

I am writing a user program for a simulation software. There is a variable called adj_elect05. The following chunk of code gets called over and over again. Each time it gets called, I want adj_elect05 (which has a numeric value) to be incremented by a certain amount, and then have that amount written to a file. This is the code that works:

```
increment = -10

adj_elect05 = adj_elect05 + increment

oct_voltages = io.open(O_V, "a+")
oct_voltages:write("\n", adj_elect05) 
oct_voltages:close ()
```

In the file I get a list of numbers: -10, -20, -30, and so on. The problem is I need to give adj_elect05 a generic name so that it can be changed later on without having to change every instance it shows up so I wrote:

```
increment = -10
octupole_v = adj_elect05

octupole_v = octupole_v + increment

oct_voltages = io.open(O_V, "a+")
oct_voltages:write("\n", octupole_v) 
oct_voltages:close ()
```

With this, I get -10 written to the file for ever time the code runs, rather than having it decrease by ten every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that code in a loop/function? Are you assigning from `adj_elect05` each time in the loop/function? Because you never change `adj_elect05` so if you assign to `octupole_v` from `adj_elect05` each time through the loop/function (in the second snippet) you undo your increment modification each time.

Comment: It is in a function. So is there no way to rename adj_elect05? Since octupole_v is changed in the first loop, and then assigned to adj_elect05 in the second loop, I would expect adj_elect05 to be incremented.

Comment: `octupole_v` isn't a reference to the `adj_elect05` variable. It is an independent variable which is assigned the same value. Changes to `octupole_v` don't change `adj_elect05`. Try `a=5; b=a; print(a); print(b); b="foo"; print(a); print(b)` for example.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense. So is there a way to create a reference to adj_elect05?

Comment: Not really, no. You can use a table and update its fields or you can assign back to the global at the end or you can not use a separate variable at all.

Comment: Alright, I will try another method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use local variable:

```
local increment = -10
local octupole_v = adj_elect05
octupole_v = octupole_v + increment
```

By default variables are considered global (unlike Python).